# Самописная CMS

Tags: php, cms

Многие используют самописные CMS. Какие их преимущества по сравнению с распространенными (joomla, drupal, wordpress и т.д.)?

Comment: [Движок для высоконагруженного сайта][1] Много полезных коментов


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/35697/движок-для-высоконагруженного-сайта

Comment: Самописная это хорошо, но как по мне, то проще взять готовую, но с открытым кодом и доработать. Меньше затрат времени и быстрее поучаешь результат. Это если есть ограничения по времени; если ограничений нет, то да, лучше самому курить тему. Я когда начинал, то за основу брал <https://coba.tools/opencart>.

Answer (score 12):

Во-первых, своя CMS обладает всеми нужными свойствами.
Во-вторых, свою CMS легче расширять.
В-третьих, взломщику самописная CMS неизвестна, поэтому он может и не понять, откуда начинать ломать.
В-четвертых (вытекает из во-вторых), вряд ли кто-то согласится поддерживать чужую CMS, поэтому с заказчика можно и за это денег содрать.
В-пятых, фраза "на нашей CMS работает уже %n% сайтов" значительно повышает самооценку программиста/ов.

Хотя, зачастую, самописная CMS изнутри являет собой такое г-но и по смыслу, и по стилю кодирования, и в плане безопасности, что хоть стой, хоть падай.
Зато своя.

Comment: "зачастую, самописная CMS изнутри являет собой такое г-но" - зачастую, купленная - тоже...

Answer (score 10):

Уже второй год работаю над своей CMS. Из самых весомых плюсов могу выделить один единственный в самом деле важный. Я получил огромный опыт в разработке, я начал с уважением относиться к другим ЦМС, я осмыслил детали, на которые раньше даже внимания не обращал. И чем дальше я работаю в этом направлении, тем больше я приближаюсь к профессионализму. Потому что осознание собственных ошибок это первый шаг к понимаю чужих.

Comment: Уважаю. А применяете ее при создании сайтов?

Comment: Порядка 60 проектов уже реализовано.

Comment: Есть ли она на Github? Можно ссылку, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

1. Никаких преимуществ (уж точно перед тремя перечисленными)
2. Куча еще не отловленных глюков и не доработок. (Над своей CMS работаете вы + сосед по лестничной площадке, а над joomla например целое сообщество - одно дело движок написать, другое его в актуальном состоянии поддерживать и постоянно пополнять новыми расширениями )
3. "У самописной есть больше вероятность, что она будет более защищенная" вот это только при условии что ее разработывал весьма сильный программист и что исходников для изучения дыр в сети не появится - хотя народные умельцы не сломают так уронят (это без вариантов).
4. "свою CMS легче расширять" - Опять же она должна быть для этого грамотно спроектирована,
5. "зачастую, самописная CMS изнутри являет собой такое г-но и по смыслу, и по стилю кодирования, и в плане безопасности, что хоть стой, хоть падай." - ЗОЛОТЫЕ СЛОВА
6. "вряд ли кто-то согласится поддерживать чужую CMS" - Как студия занимающаяся созданием сайтов, мы даже не беремся копаться в самопальных движках тк это себе дороже и заказчики понимают что лучше сделать сайт на популярной CMS - с ней в будущем возникнет множество проблем
7. "стоимость поддержки самописной может быть меньше" - это ерунда киньте обьявку на фриланс с текстом "Нужно подправить немного в joomla/wordpress... " и сразу куча откликов т.к. с известными CMS работают и и знают их многие - и разбираться самому в неизвестной CMS будет дороже и по времени и по деньгам
8. [[@Arni](/users/3748/arni)](/users/3748/arni) "Я получил огромный опыт в разработке"  - Полностью согласен это   РЕАЛЬНЫЙ (один единственный) ПЛЮС  работы над своей CMS

Comment: Сразу прослеживается ярая ненависть к самописным CMS И восторгиние Wp, joomla, drupal... ИМХО вы написали как подросток максималист, у вас - все что wp, joomla, drupal белое а остальное - черное, каГбы еще серый цвет есть, не? И практически со всеми пунктами можно спорить и там по факту будет ваше слово против моего...<br>
Вообще сам вопрос с холиварным контекстом ^^

Comment: 1 В действительности я не против самописных CMS - главное чтобы они мне в работе над сайтами не попадались - а такие были и больше не хочется. 
Весь этот "подростковый максимализм" это опыт работы в web студии, а не теоретические рассуждения. 

2 Я не восторгаюсь "Wp, joomla, drupal...", они просто лучше самопала и сними проще заработать.

3 "каГбы еще серый цвет есть, не" Да есть, я о нем упоминул в пункте 8 своего ответа выше

Comment: Судя по вашему отзыву, вы не против самописных CMS, если они написаны грамотным программистом. Но вы наотрез отказываетесь работать с ними, чтобы не тратить времени на изучение. Тогда к вам два вопроса:  
1. Как вы поступаете, если задача предполагает работу с известной системой, но с которой у вас опыта работы нет?  
2. Как вы поступите, если система неизвестна, но открыта и с документацией?  
К слову, я не против пообщаться с вами в аське. Не дадите номер? =)

Comment: C неизвестной системой буду работать только если это интересно  и предпологает работу сней в будущем либо на долгий срок. И конечно же изучу ее коли приспичит.

Comment: Жаль поднимать тему вверх, на раз откопал.

>C неизвестной системой буду работать только если это интересно и >предпологает работу сней в будущем

А если начальник сказал что нужно работать именно с ней, а желания нет? Вы уволитесь? Думаю нет! практически во всем соглашусь с @AlexWindHope.

Comment: Начальник по счастью адекватный и самописок на поддержку не берет

Comment: Скажу как постоянный заказчик. Расстрелял бы все студии в полном составе, которые самописное гумно клиентам продают. Тему Лебедева в первых рядах.

У самописных CMS есть только один смысл - тянуть деньги из заказчика до тех пор, пока он случайно не выяснит что весь "супер функционал" за который он платит, можно поставить тремя кликами в друпале или в вордпрессе. Вместе с "мега дизайном", за который тоже заплачено.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых вы знаете свою кмс, во-вторых в ней только нужные вам функции, в-третьих она написана в вашем стиле программирования, что позволяет вам её без проблем редактировать.
Плюсов много, главное знать что делаете.

Answer (score 1):

В том случае, если готовая CMS не требует доводки-доделки, она выгоднее, чем самописная. Если же доводка требуется, то стоимость поддержки самописной может быть меньше, потому что не нужно 1) учить язык CMS, 2) разбираться в чужом коде, 3) разбираться в чужом окружении.

Answer (score 1):

У самописной есть больше вероятность, что она будет более защищенная. Так как взломщик, не будет знать, с чем имеет дело. А в распространенных, не успела выйти, как нашли кучу дыр и выложили в интернете.

Хотя и самописную можно по ошибке или по незнанию дырявую сделать

Answer (score 1):

Я, как автор сапописного сркипта (cms) хочу перечислить пару плюсов:

1) Скорость работы в разы выше (зависит от прямых рук автора cms)
2) Админка, если таковая имеется, радует глаз.
3) Легко писать модули
4) Автор ни от кого не зависит, то есть от обновления скрипта у разработчика
5) Интеграция с любым существующим форумом упрощается раза в 4.
6) Так как cms не используется в "широких кругах", то её исходный код неизвестен, а следовательно шансы, что её взломают, падают.

Ну а теперь минусы:
1-10) Минусов нет!

Answer (score 1):

До сих пор пишу свою CMS уже 3ю версию(5й год системе), но скорее всего 3я не выйдет по идейным соображениям, выйдет совершенно другая CMS основанная на совершенно другой структуре и разработана совершенно иначе.

На ней написано около 30-40 сайтов + скорее всего еще порядка 20-30, написано на ней же вторым разработчиком. так что меня показатель в 100 сайтов вполне устраивает,

> В-пятых, фраза "на нашей CMS работает
> уже %n% сайтов" значительно повышает
> самооценку программиста/ов.

В точку!

Своя CMS это как твой инструмент разработки, твой детище, твои грехи и мольбы о помощи. Кто не писал свой велосипед, то не поймет. Хочется охватить все и сразу, неа ничего не получится. Сразу и все только сыр в мышеловке.

Писать ей следует грамотно с хорошим подходом и документировано, а иначе грош цена системе, как в прямом так и в переносном смысле.

В данный момент "новая" система разрабатывается 3мя программистами.
Отдельно структура и взаимодействие БД и таблиц в ней.
Отдельно ПО.

Единственное что, пишется на всем известном PHP. Планируется перенести на другой язык. но это уже будущее еще на 2-3 года.

Comment: Изобретатели велосипедов? Интересно кто оплачивает такую работу - заказчики которые не в курсе что есть CMS в принципе?

Answer (score 1):

Единственным преимуществом своей CMS перед чужими и распространенными можно считать то, что она будет более понятной и "родной" что ли. В своей CMS точно не захочется быстренько клепать костыли. Ибо потом могут выйти совсем непонятные вещи.

Рано или поздно захочется написать что-то хорошее, которое в будущем можно будет модифицировать и приспособить к новым условиям. Для самописки это не такая проблема. С распространенными дела обстоят иначе. В виду того, что иногда приходится перелопачивать все ядро, чтобы понять как, что и куда, желание остывает и пишется скоренький костыль (ну, или если упертость разработчика зашкаливает, дело доходит до финиша).

К антипреимуществам своей CMS можно отнести тот факт, что для распространенных CMS разрабатывается большое количество разнообразных модулей. Для своей же разрабатывается не такое большое количество модулей (да и, скорее всего, эти модули будут интегрироваться в ядро). Это связано либо с тем, что просто нет на это времени, либо фантазия ограничена насущными заботами. Как говорится: "Одна голова хорошо, а две - лучше".

Но несомненный плюс своей CMS - это "заточенность" под определенный сервис. Мало кто делает самописки универсальными.